# How to separate a comma separated string points

Tags: python

I have a comma separated string **s** that I want to turn it to list of **P** as shown below
`s = "(2,3), (12, 30), (40, 50), (5, 1), (12, 10), (3, 4)"`

```
P = [Point(2, 3), Point(12, 30), 
    Point(40, 50), Point(5, 1), 
    Point(12, 10), Point(3, 4)]
```

My code below does not work, How would I resolve this?

```
x = s.split()
print(x)
print(len(x))
P = [Point(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split without a delimiter just splits on spaces so you end up with `["(2,3),"...]` etc which still won't help you, so you can either continue to split and convert to numbers as needed, or just treat it as a tuple you need to evaluate and then work from that

```
from ast import literal_eval
P = [Point(*x) for x in literal_eval(s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.

```
s = "(2,3), (12, 30), (40, 50), (5, 1), (12, 10), (3, 4)"
x = s.split(,)
P = []

for i in x:
    x1 = f"Point{i}
    P.append(x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex` for this.

```
import re

s = "(2,3), (12, 30), (40, 50), (5, 1), (12, 10), (3, 4)"
pattern = re.compile('\(([^\)]+)\)')

matches = re.findall(pattern, s)
res = []
for i in matches:
    temp = f'Point({i})'
    res.append(temp)

print(res)
```

```
['Point(2,3)', 'Point(12, 30)', 'Point(40, 50)', 'Point(5, 1)', 'Point(12, 10)', 'Point(3, 4)']
```